# Difference between 「にかかわらず」 and 「にもかかわらず」

Tags: particles, compounds, linguistics

I would like to know the difference between 「にかかわらず」 and 「にもかかわらず」 with regard to the semantics of the predicate-argument relation.

Do they express the same semantic relation (non-causality?)? or does one have a broader meaning?

[EDIT]

As for an example, let's consider 「で」 and 「でもって」.

- 「で」 might be used to mark the instrumental case, so does 「でもって」.
- 「で」 might be used to mark the locative case ; 「でもって」 does not.

What about 「にかかわらず」 and 「にもかかわらず」?

Answer (score 5):

There are many usages, but 「にかかわらず」 and 「にもかかわらず」are different.
(You can't replace them)

When you want to insist you won't care about something:

```
何か(A) にかかわらず 何か(B) をする。
Without caring about something(A), do something(B).
Without worrying about something(A), do something(B).

It's similar to:
何か に拘らず 何か をする。
何か を気にせず 何か をする。
何か を問わず 何か をする。
何か を意識せず 何か をする。

Sample:
学歴 にかかわらず 社員を募集する。
```

When you want to insist there is something else involved:

```
何か にかかわらず
Not only something, but also ...

Sample:
鳥 にかかわらず 人間にも影響のある病。
```

にもかかわらず is used when you want to insist on something negative, something you didn't want to occur. Also when you get mad at someone.

```
出来事(A) にもかかわらず 何か(B) が起きた。
-> Even though there was a fact(A), something bad(B) happened.

Sample:
妊娠している にもかかわらず タバコを吸っている。

何か(A) した にもかかわらず 何か(B) が起きた。
-> Even though something(A) was done (in the past, on purpose to prevent something), something bad(B) happened.

Sample:
対策した にもかかわらず また問題が起きた。
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I understand these two forms are different with respect to modality and/or topicalization. However, my concern is about their logical form, that is, does the relation NON_CAUSALITY(x,y) holds across their different usages? Martin (1975, p. 583), for instance, treats にかかわらず and にもかかわらず as the same phrasal posposition...

Comment: I don't know if I understood what you mean with non-causality(x, y).
The first usage of にかかわらず and the last usage of にもかかわらず above are not really non-causality usages. But in the other ones they both express non-causality and the relation seems to be the same.
X にかかわらず Y  -> X is not the cause for Y.
X にもかかわらず Y -> X is not the cause for Y.

Comment: かなり専門的な質問に対し、「使用例」をメインに回答されている点が、質問者さんの満足感を得られていない原因ではないかと思われます。質問の中で使用されている、言語学の専門用語がひとつも回答の中で使用されていないことは、やはり不自然な質疑応答として捉えられかねないという気がします。失礼を承知で書かせていただきました。

Comment: 彼の言う因果関係以外にも用途が存在するため、意味関係はそもそも全く別なので、多少ズレていることは承知の上一旦こういう回答で接触してみました。用途が分かればもしかすれば彼の専門知識で答えが分かるかと。

Comment: 曖昧な箇所がいくつかあったと思いますので、質問を編集させてもらいます。もし不明瞭な点があれば、またコメントをお願いします。

Comment: 一応上記に代表的な用途は網羅したつもりですが、いずれも「にもかかわらず」「にかかわらず」は差し替えると意味不明になる（文法的に合おうが）、というのが自分の回答になります。各用途に専門的な英語で名前を付けるのは自分にはちょっと難しいので、すみませんが私の回答は参考までにここまでとさせていただきます。